# How to Get entity by Unique Key using Dapper.Contrib?

Tags: c#, dapper, dapper-contrib

I have an object, assume

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    int TheId { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Age { get; set; }
}
```

`TheId` is my auto increment column and `Name` is my unique key. When saving a user, I want to check its existence by:

```
var user= connection.Get<User>("John");
```

But, because of my Key is not `Name` but `TheId`, I can't do this. If I set `Name` property as `[KeyExplicit]` that time when I want to save my user by:

```
connection.Insert(myUser);
```

This time, dapper expect `TheId` property filled by me, not let database to auto increment.

So, I wonder is there an elegant way to achieve to mark some property or properties to dapper take into account while searching on db. I don't want to search by `Guid` but unique keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are willing to [`Get`](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib#features) by property other than key.

This is not supported by dapper-contrib. For `Get`, you should use key field only. This is not possible even if that other property is unique key. Any other adjustments you are doing (setting `[KeyExplicit]` on `Name` property) is not the proper way to handle this; it will create other problems as you can see.

For `Get` with other properties, better alternative is to use Dapper directly bypassing Contrib.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54454928/5779732